# django session midleware is working locally, but it doesn't on production

Tags: python, django, middleware

I'm working on a project that I don't want anyone to access my media through a direct link ex : https://www.xxx.sa/media/reports_images/report_bfc4242c.png.
As i want only admin to reach this image through its link, and it works locally, but on production ,anyone with the link can access the image
I used session middleware and it works perfect but when it comes to the production, it doesn't.

Here's my code

```
class GatedContent(MiddlewareMixin):
def process_request(self, request):
    path = request.path
    user = request.user
    disallow_user = False
    for gated in settings.GATED_CONTENT:
        if path.startswith(gated) or path.endswith(gated):
            report_uuid = path.split("/")[-1].split('.')[0]

            if gated == REPORT_IMAGE_PATH:

                report_image = get_object_or_404(ReportImage, uuid=report_uuid)
            elif gated == COMMENT_IMAGE_PATH:
                report_image = get_object_or_404(ReportComment, uuid=report_uuid)

            if user.is_staff:
                disallow_user = False
            elif report_image.report.triage:
                if report_image.report.triage.user == user:
                    disallow_user = False
                else:
                    disallow_user = True
            else:
                disallow_user = True
            break
    # Validate the user is an authenticated/valid user
    if disallow_user:
        raise Http404
```

So, what's wrong here

Comment: What error do you get (if you get any)? What 'is not working' exactly? Do you have an example use case on test vs prod? You need to be more specific in order to get some help :)

Comment: @babis21 
well, i don't get an error, as you see in the code, i want only admin users to reach the image through the link, so i used the middleware, and it works, no one but the admin can reach the image through the link, anyone else will get 404 page
but this doesn't happen on production

Comment: Your media files probably aren't served by Django in production and are served by something like nginx instead, in which case the request doesn't even reach Django as you have configuration causing nginx to serve the files.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It seems that you're right I don't know too much about the deployment so i have a question 
the project has alot of logic based on requests, and all of it works well, so is it a problem with the middleware only?

Comment: No it's not a problem with the middleware, as I said you have a server like nginx serving your requests. When a user makes requests it will first reach nginx which will decide whether it needs to serve some static / media files on it's own or forward the request to Django. Given the assumption that nginx is configured to serve static & media files your request doesn't even reach Django so obviously no middleware / views run. If you want requests to go through Django first and then be served by nginx, use a feature like https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/